# Strange issue with outer join

Tags: mysql, sql, t-sql

I am trying to understand a query that has an outer join and is not behaving in a way that I expected.

The scenario is I have SQL that looks similar to this:

```
with x as (
  select id 
  from a
),
y as (
  select id
  from b
)

select x.id
from x 
full outer join y on x.id = y.id
where (x.id is null or y.id is null)
```

Now suppose there are no null id's on table or table b as I have check them individually.

If so how could it be that the above SQL returns rows that have nulls in x.id when in the x cte we checked there were no nulls returned for id? But if I change the full outer join to a left join there are no returned rows.

That is the scenario I am dealing with and trying to understand. It may be due to my lack of awareness on how the outer join works.

Thank you

Comment: Please clarify which RDBMS you're using (it's obviously not MySQL)

Answer (score 0):

That is what an outer join does.  If there are no matches, then the columns from the *other* table are assigned a `NULL` value.

This is finding `id`s that are in one table but not the other.